# A non-positive product of positive elements in the unital $C^*$-algebra $C([0, 1], \mathbb{C})$

Tags: functional-analysis, c-star-algebras

Consider the unital $C^*$-algebra $C([0,1], \mathbb{C})$, and its positive elements
$f : x ↦ \sqrt{1-x^2}$ and $g : x ↦ x^2$. Then we have, for all $x ∈ [0,1]$:

$$(fg)^*(x) = g^*f^*(x) = g^*\left(\overline{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\right) = g^*\left(\sqrt{1-x^2}\right) = \overline{1-x^2} = 1-x^2 ≠ \sqrt{1-x^4} = f(x^2) = fg(x).$$

Thus, as $fg$ is not self-adjoint, it is not positive. Have I found an example of a unital $C^*$-algebra $A$ with positive elements $f, g$ such that $fg$ is not positive? I would say yes, were it not for Example VIII.3.2 in Conway's book, which says an element $h$ of $C(X)$ is positive if and only if $(\forall x ∈ X)(h(x) ≥ 0)$, which is certainly the case for $h = fg$...  (In fact I used this property to say that $f, g$ were positive in the first place..)

Comment: The algebra is commutative so the product of positive elements is positive. Why do you apply composition instead of multiplication of functions ?

Comment: Cause I'm an idiot :p

Comment: There are $C^*$-algebras, where product of two positive elements need not be positive, because the elements do not commute. For example $2\times 2,$ matrices form a noncommutatve $C^*$-algebra with respect to a certain norm.

Comment: You shouldn't be discouraged by posting something which is not correct at times. Sometimes crazy ideas lead to interesting unexpected results, that nobody predicted.